# Printing directory path without file name

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I am new to linux and need assistance. I have a file which contains the list of file name with their paths. ex:

```
$ cat /home/user/files.txt

/xyz/abc/xxx/abc.sh
/xyz/nnn/111.dat
/xyz/mmm/yyy/sss/rrr/123.log
```

How do I print just the directory structure and not the file names, please note directory depths are not constant and extension as well.

Output I need (The slash `/` as the end is not required)

```
/xyz/abc/xxx/
/xyz/nnn/
/xyz/mmm/yyy/sss/rrr/
```

Please suggest, thanks in advance.

Comment: In bash: dir="${fullpath%/*}"

Comment: **ls -d */** [blahblah]

Comment: Are all your files going to have an extension like the ones in you question ? (`.sh` and `.log` for instance)

Comment: Hi Martin, The file contains the list of files which are modified recently and majority of them have extension, so lets just say yes.

Comment: @69 420 1970 , it only works on command line and not in a file with list of files

Comment: You might find a workaround in copying your file and then removing the files at the end using something like a regular expression in vim that selects the end of the line with the dot and stuff.

Answer (score 4):

```bsh
cat file | while read name; do
   dirname "$name"
done
```

Comment: `echo "${name%/*}"` is a built-in substitution: that would be much faster than a new dirname process for every name.

Answer (score 4):

If it is certain that the last component is indeed the filename, you can use `awk` for this:

```
awk -F'/' -v OFS='/' '{$NF=""}1' file.txt
```

This will use the `/` as field separator for input and output, and set the last field (i.e. the filename) to the empty string. The `1` outside the rule block instructs `awk` to print the line, including all modifications.

Alternatively, use `sed`:

```
sed -E 's|/[^/]+$|/|' file.txt
```

will replace the pattern "one `/` followed by any characters that are *not* slashes up to the end of the line" by the `/`, thereby effectively eliminating the last part of the path, which is the filename.